# How can I convert a string to the idna coded, encoding with 'idna' coded failed

Tags: python, encoding, smtp

I have a string, which should be a stmp server in a later step for python.

The string is (little anonymized):

`outlook-stg.d-a-tf.de/mapi/emsmdb/?MailboxId=cf27be4f-8605-40e4-94ab-d8cea3cc03bc@test.com`

For sure the error is:

> UnicodeError: encoding with 'idna' codec failed (UnicodeError: label
>   empty or too long)

Which I understand is a problem with the name how I want to adress the server: [label empty or too long - python urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103126/label-empty-or-too-long-python-urllib2)

But how can I convert it in the right format? I also tried: [Encoding with 'idna' codec failed in RethinkDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465259/encoding-with-idna-codec-failed-in-rethinkdb)

With this code: `.encode("idna")` but this also is the same error.

Comment: Please have a look at my reply if it helps, but I fear there may be some ambiguities around "I have a string, which should be a stmp server in a later step for python." and "But how can I convert it in the right format? " so I took some assumptions when writing my reply. If you can add additional context to your question or maybe some piece of code, we may be able to improve the answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

IDNA is an algorithm used to encode domain names, or hostnames. What you provide as example is an URL, so it includes characters that can not work in a domain name and hence can not be encoded and hence your error.

You need to separate the domain (host) name from the rest, apply IDNA only to it (but useless in your example as your hostname is purely ASCII already), and reconstruct your URL.

The specific error you quote comes from the following fact: as IDNA deals with names, per the DNS definition, it works at the label level. A label is somethings between dots, so first step is to split things.
Your string is then handled that way:

1. `outlook-stg`
2. `d-a-tf`
3. `de/mapi/emsmdb/?MailboxId=cf27be4f-8605-40e4-94ab-d8cea3cc03bc@test`
4. `com`

And a label in the DNS can not be more than 63 bytes. Your third string, even for now not considering that it has disallowed characters (like `@`)  that can never happen in a domain name, even with IDNA encoding, is 68 bytes long, hence the exact error you get.

If I artificially shrink it I then get another error, as expected based on above explanations:

```
>>> print(idna.encode('outlook-stg.d-a-tf.de/mapi/emsmdb/?MId=cf27be4f-8605-40e4-94ab-d8cea3cc03bc@test.com'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 358, in encode
    s = alabel(label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 270, in alabel
    ulabel(label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 304, in ulabel
    check_label(label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/idna/core.py", line 261, in check_label
    raise InvalidCodepoint('Codepoint {0} at position {1} of {2} not allowed'.format(_unot(cp_value), pos+1, repr(label)))
idna.core.InvalidCodepoint: Codepoint U+002F at position 3 of 'de/mapi/emsmdb/?mid=cf27be4f-8605-40e4-94ab-d8cea3cc03bc@test' not allowed
```

(U+002F is `/` of course, another character disallowed in a domain name, hence rejected during IDNA encoding)

Note that there are rules also to encoding "non ascii characters" in other parts of the URL, that is the path, which is why the top governing standard is now IRI: RFC 3987
It says, even if in a convoluted way, exactly the above:

> Replace the ireg-name part of the IRI by the part converted using
>   the    ToASCII operation specified in section 4.1 of [RFC3490] on each
>   dot-separated label, and by using U+002E (FULL STOP) as a label
>   separator, with the flag UseSTD3ASCIIRules set to TRUE, and with the
>   flag AllowUnassigned set to FALSE for creating IRIs and set to TRUE
>   otherwise.

So, depending on your needs, you should:

1. Parse your string as an URI/IRI (with a proper library, do not expect to do it properly with a regex yourself)
2. Now that you have the hostname part, you can apply IDNA on it, as needed (but the URI/IRI parsing library may do the work for you in fact already, so double check)
3. And reconstruct the full URI/IRI if you want after that.

Comment: So in other words the actual server name here is simply just `outlook-stg.d-a-tf.de` and we can't really guess without additional context how the rest is supposed to be used (though the MAPI moniker vaguely suggests some Microsoft atrocity).

Comment: @tripleee Yes the hostname is `outlook-stg.d-a-tf.de` and if you had to apply IDNA to something, that would be the only part to apply it on (but here it would return the same result, the input is all 7-bits ASCII already so that is a no change under IDNA). I considered in my reply the string as being an URL, and if so, IDNA applies possibly only to only the hostname part of it, not the other parts. OP has "I have a string, which should be a stmp server in a later step for python." I do not know how to have a  "smtp server" from that string, except for the hostname. Some context may be missing.