# Get smtp server of outlook business computer

Tags: outlook, smtp

I am searching for the smtp server of my outlook account. However, I am in my business enviorment, so I think i am not able to find it.

Here is a famous thread to: [Figure out smtp server host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461154/figure-out-smtp-server-host/1461164)

Butsomehow this is not working out, so I tried it in the outlook settings:
[image]

If i compare it with other [ways](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HK5gvsVyNI) (example):
[image]

I think the problem is that I am behind a microsoft exchange server. Any chance to figure it out?

The error I get when I try to use the server above I get this error: [How can I convert a string to the idna coded, encoding with 'idna' coded failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155219/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-the-idna-coded-encoding-with-idna-coded-failed)

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for the network name of the outward facing SMTP server in your Exchange environment? There is no programmatic way to figure it out. Asking your Exchange admin is probably the only way.

Comment: I was scared of this answer...but anyway thx, fits to other topics around here